# How to do a dynamic password in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, passwords, inno-setup

I want to know how can to create a password that rotate in Inno Setup?
Something similar to a "Token"?
Or search in a SharePoint list?
I don't want that always be a same.

Is it possible?

Do you have other suggestion?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CheckPassword` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CheckPassword) instead of [`Password` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_password).

```pascal
[Code]

// Passwords cache in case their retrieval is time consuming
var
  Passwords: array of string;

function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  SHA1: string;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  // CheckPassword may be called before any other code
  // (including InitializeSetup), so any initialization has to happen
  // in the function itself.
  Count := 5;
  if GetArrayLength(Passwords) = 0 then
  begin
    Log('Initializing hashes');
    SetArrayLength(Passwords, Count);
    Passwords[0] := 'df65784979efcda967c88de7098a5a106101064e';
    Passwords[1] := 'b78baf5db4b1498ed075b8e6accd0b5ff51e20ec';
    Passwords[2] := 'aaf70585b9a2662c911392b7573c739cecea0e56';
    Passwords[3] := '3ab4222e2d0000012e6c7381437178fab398e8aa';
    Passwords[4] := '5473ccc879a8167a6a77b387a916f7c9ca05894f';
  end;

  SHA1 := GetSHA1OfUnicodeString(Password);
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    if SHA1 = Passwords[I] then
    begin
      Log(Format('Password matches hash %d', [I]));
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Log(Format('Password matches none of our %d hashes', [Count]));
  Result := False;
end;
```