# Dynamic password in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need that my program be protected with a dynamic password that includes the current date.

I need just the month or the day or the hour or the minute.

I tried this code to include the day into the password:

```pascal
[Setup]
Password=Password!{code:DateTime|0}

[Code]
function DateTime (Param: string): string;
begin
    Result := GetDateTimeString('dd', #0, #0);
end;
```

But it's not working.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Password` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_password) cannot contain any [constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts), let alone [scripted constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

So your script makes the password be literally `Password!{code:DateTime|0}`.

Instead, use [`CheckPassword` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CheckPassword):

```pascal
[Code]

function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Password = ('Password!' + GetDateTimeString('dd', #0, #0)));
end;
```

---

Though safer than comparing against a literal string (which can be seen in .exe binary) is comparing a checksum.

See [How to do a dynamic password in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34626502/850848)